# Repeating dataframe name in drop function

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas so can someone please give me an insight into the following:

I would like to drop some outliers and the following code does not work:

```
train = train.drop(['GrLivArea']>4000) & (['SalePrice']<300000)
```

when i try: `train = train.drop(train[(train['GrLivArea']>4000) & (train['SalePrice']<300000)].index)`, it works.

Can someone please explain why I need to state 'train' two times before the column name (GrLivArea) when I indicated the dataframe I am referring to (by stating train.drop)

thanks alot.

Comment: the drop method requires columns to be mentioned, the first one has no reference to the dataframe - the function has no idea what to do with it, and as such it fails. the second one however worked because the rows that should be dropped are returned, and since drop can work on both axis and columns, the drop method works.

Comment: please share sample df

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
train = train[(train['GrLivArea']>4000) & (train['SalePrice']<300000)]
```

Comment: Edited. I still do not see the need to use drop here.

Comment: I agree with you on that. Downvote removed/Upvoted :)

Comment: Also, careful as OP wants to remove/drop those values, not keep them